# Bootstrap 4 form column lines up below another column in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a bootstrap form that is acting weird. The last column in a row has two elements in it. The last element is displaying below the first one instead of to it's right.

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select id="ExpMonth" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Exp. Month</option>
      <? for($x=1;$x<13;$x++){?>
      <option>
      <? if(strlen($x) < 2){?>0<?}?><?=$x?>
      </option>
      <? } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <select id="ExpYear" class="form-control">
   <option selected>Exp. Year</option>
   <? for ($x=$thisyear;$x<=2034;$x++){?>
   <option><?=$x?></option>
   <? } ?>
  </select>
 </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CVV2" placeholder="Security Code"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this part

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CVV2" placeholder="Security Code"><i 
  class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CVV2" placeholder="Security Code">
      <span style="padding-top:5px;">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<div class="form-row">
```

(first line of your code) you can try this

```
<div class="form-row row">
```

Just by adding row to the class...try it

Comment: Could you please give a clearer example of how to add "row" to the class...perhaps type out the line that you are suggesting.  Thanks.

Comment: Just replace class="form-row" with class="form-row row"

Comment: That did nothing

Comment: I know this is old but, hell yeah this worked for me. Been banging my head against a brick wall for hours trying to work this out, your suggestion worked - thanks.